# UITableView Multiple Checkmark Selection

Tags: uitableview, selection

Having read a couple of the questions asked relating to this, I can get the functionality to work. However my list is long and scrollable, so when I scroll up and down the selection of the checkmarks are all over the place. selectedIndexes is a `NSMutableArray`. Any ideas?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [selectedIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];

    } 
    else {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        [selectedIndexes removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];

    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

}
```

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` i have the following check.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [natures objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSString *cellValue = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedIndexes.count; i++) {
        NSUInteger num = [[selectedIndexes objectAtIndex:i] intValue];

        if (num == indexPath.row) {
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        }
        else {
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
        }

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to modify your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to be the following:

```
// Assume cell is not checked -- if it is the loop below will check it.
[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
for (int i = 0; i < selectedIndexes.count; i++) {
        NSUInteger num = [[selectedIndexes objectAtIndex:i] intValue];

        if (num == indexPath.row) {
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
            // Once we find a match there is no point continuing the loop
            break;
        }
    }
```

You need to do this because a reusable cell might have the checkmark set -- so you need to clear it. Hope this helps.

Incidentally, using an `NSSet` would probably be a more elegant solution!

Comment: I still get the same error. So if I select items 6,7 when I scroll down, 2 random items are selected.

Comment: Well it it almost certainly to do with your reusable cells. Perhaps post all of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Oh I see the problem -- give me a moment.

Comment: I dont think this is quite right, how long is your tableview list? lets say there's 30 items and the tableview shows 10 at a time for instance. If I select the 5th item, and I scroll to the next 20 and then back to the previous 10, its not selected properly.

Perhaps the rows are not recorded properly as in 5th item is translated to the 15th item on the following scroll if that make sense.

Comment: yes i did. what i think it does is shows the first 10 so the indexPath.row is 0-9. Then if i show say the next 20 by scrolling down, the same indexPath.row is 0-9. I could be wrong but I'll need to debug/nslog to check.

Comment: If you have way 30 rows then the index paths will be 0-29 -- the index path is not affected by what is visible. When you select the row with indexPath.row = 5, say, you should add that to your array (which you appear to do) later in cellForRowAtIndexPath when you seach the array you should find 5 and select the row. Of course I do not have your code and a debugger in front of me, so a few breakpoints or NSLogs should help you figure out that is going wrong. Should be straightforward enough. Good Luck!

Comment: Hmm I think what i forgot to mention that the tableview has sections. So that's why reselecting was all over the shop. How can you keep track of the section and also the row? -- Come to think of it, an array of IndexPath's should be suffice.

Comment: In that case you need to put the NSIndexPath and not just the row number into your array (or set). You can use -[NSIndexPath isEqual:] to compare them.

Comment: Sorry just a final question, is there such thing as objectAtIndexPath for an NSMutableArray (just checked -nil)? I've populated the UITableView from an array of objects (in sections) by referencing its name only. I've used the same logic as above to checkmark each item I select. Now I want to check the objects which are selected. At the moment I need to iterate through the SelectedItems array, then get the array of objects using the indexpath.section and then retrieving the object with the indexpath.row. Any easier way to do this?

Comment: No there's not. But here's what you do: Instead of `[selectedIndexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]]` say `[selectedIndexes addObject:indexPath]` so instead of storing the row you store the index path. And obviously from there update the code that uses NSNumber to do the same thing, but using NSIndexPath. Also remember the hint: if you use `NSSet` it will be much easier (you won't need a loop). Good luck!

Comment: selectedIndexes does indeed add indexPath objects because I'll need the section as well as the row. From my global list of objects, I just wanted to know an easy way to reference them using the indexPath's from the selectedIndexes. I need to check what NSSet is. I'm from a c# background and all this syntax is extremely weird :)

Comment: Oh now I get what you're asking. For your main array what you are doing is fine.... BUT what you could do is use nested arrays. Have one array that is indexed by section holding arrays that hold the information for each row... Understand what I mean?

Comment: Hmm I think my current way might be the best way. So once all the items are selected, I just iterate through those indexPath's and using the section and row, I can retrieve the object from the global list. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 21):

For multiple selection you just need on `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```

and

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = NO; 
    // if you don't use a custom image then tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    tableViewCell.accessoryView.hidden = YES;
    // if you don't use a custom image then tableViewCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: That works in the moment, but how do you save the results so that the next time you run the app, the selectedIndexes are remembered? Is a multi-dimensional array, the best bet?

Comment: That question would fit for another stack overflow question. In advance, it can be saved in NSUserDefaults for example.

Comment: Thanks Raphael. Good idea to use NSUserDefaults. If I get stuck, I'll ask again.

Comment: Thanks Raphael,I trying your code and works perfect but i check one row and then several row add check automatically. I did't understand why this situation happen.

Comment: @fozoglu it's probably some weird logic somewhere. Can you try to just have this on your delegate methods and see if this issue persists? Maybe you want to share your code on a new SO question.

Answer (score 1):

No need to maintain separate array for storing selected rows.
Use native method `indexPathsForSelectedRows` to get selected cells indexPath array. And just check arrayContains current IndexPath in cellForRow method as given below:

```
NSArray *indexPaths = [tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];

if ([indexPaths containsObject:indexPath]) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}

#pragma mark- select/deselect 

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
```